# Why must the outside limits of an iterated be constant?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, 3d

My book claims that in an iterated integral $$\int_a^b \int_{g(x)}^{h(x)} f(x, y) \, dy \, dx$$

$h$ and $j$ are allowed to be any functions of $x$ not containing $y$, but $a$ and $b$ *must* be constant with respect to both $x$ and $y$. I don't really see why $a$ and $b$ have to be constants.

Comment: $a$ and $b$ can be functions.  Functions of something other than $x$ and $y$, though.  Since $x$ and $y$ are "dummy variables" undefined outside the integrand.  Similarly, $g$ and $h$ can be functions of $x$ but not of $y$.

Comment: Suppose it was a non-iterated integral : $$ \int^{b(x)}_{a(x)} f(x)\, dx$$: the $x$ in the integrand can't "know" anything about the $x$ in the limits, right? It's like programming - which variable "x" is in scope. The $x$ in the integrand is morally speaking, a dummy variable, and you would probably - for reasons of clarity -  be better to use a different letter, e.g. $t$, in the integrand.

Comment: Did you mix up $g$ and $j$?

Comment: Do you understand why the limits in $$\int^a_b f(x)\mathrm dx$$ can't be constant?

Comment: @KristofferRyhl no, that was my question. Reading the comments above now though to try to understand

Comment: @peterag I think I kind of understand that you cannot have $\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(x) dx$, but why can't you have $\int_{a(y)}^{b(y)} f(x) dx$? I know you are integrating with respect to $y$ in the inner integral, but at this point you have already computed the inner integral so it seems like it should be irrelevant.

Comment: To make my comment clearer: suppose one  wrote $$\sum_{i=1}^i a_i.$$ This has to mean, if it means anything, $$ a_1 + \cdots + a_i$$, i.e., the $i$ in the summand is a dummy variable, and can't know anything about the $i$ in the top limit. It  would of course be stupid to use $i$ in both places though...

Comment: @Ovi: it is perfectly ok to write $$ \int^y_0 x \, dx = y^2/2.$$ Yes? Perhaps, to get the integrand $x$, 5 lines before, you calculated it as the $$ x = \int^x_0 1 \,dy. $$ The $y$ of $y^2/2$ has nothing to do with the $y$ of the $dy$. It can't! On the other hand, it might be a bit confusing to use the  variable $y$ as a "dummy" variable, and as "real" quantity, in the same problem.

Comment: Of course, I too am not being so clear in the previous - if I drink my own Kool Aid, the $x$ is a dummy variable, so what can I mean by having it calculated 5 lines earlier. Let's try again: suppose we wanted to calculate $$ g(y) = \int^y_0 f(x) \,dx.$$ Suppose, 5 lines before, I calculate $f(x)$ to be $$ f(x) = \int^x_0 1 \,dy.$$. The $y$ of $dy$ cannot have anything to do with the $y$ of $g(y)$. Right? (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) You can use $y$ in both places,as they have nothing to do with each other, but it might not be such a good idea in one problem, for reasons of clarity. Your double integral is  exactly the same thing, except that there are no 5 intervening lines.

Comment: Maybe I am beating a dead horse: are you ok with $$ x^2/2 = \int_0^x x \,dx?$$ It's 'ok', i.e., meaningful, because the $x$ 'on the outside' has "clearly" absolutely nothing to do with the dummy variable $x$ 'on the inside - but still it's a bit confusing: one should have written $t$ for dummy variable. The double integral is the same thing. ON THE OTHER HAND, one would be totally insane if the $x$ in the inside (not the $dx$), was the same $x$ as on the outside. If so, $$ \int^x_0 x \,dx = x \int^x_0 1 \, dx = x^2.$$ If one meant that, one should be shot.

Comment: If not shot - at least gently chided. Signing off?

Comment: @peterag Thanks for the help! I was offline for a couple of days, getting to read everything now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\int_a^b f(x)\,\mathrm dx
$$
We have the integral above, of course the limits $a$ and $b$ can't depend on $x$, because they simple define border around which $x$ is contained.

[image]

Now we define another function $g(x)$ as the following:
$$
g(x)=\int_{j(x)}^{h(x)}f(t)\,\mathrm dt
$$
This means that $g(x)$ is a function, whose result is what you get when you integrate $f(t)$ when $t$ is between the result of $h(x)$ and $j(x)$.

The double integral in the question is basically someone doing this:
$$
\int_a^b g(x)\,\mathrm dx
$$
Of course the limits $a$ and $b$ can't depend on $x$ since they define in which interval $x$ is given. If we substitute the definition for $g(x)$ into the integral we get the following:
$$
\int_a^b g(x)\,\mathrm dx=\int_a^b\int_{j(x)}^{h(x)}f(t)\,\mathrm dt\,\mathrm dx
$$